# How to use SharePoint 2013 Rest api to get users by role

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I am trying to use javascript to download all users of a particular role. I have this so far. It seems to get me all the users, but not all the properties of the users. I want everything such as ImageUrl and department.
And if possible, how can I put a filter on the url, so it only gets users where a certain property is equal to a certain value.

Thanks

```
var theData = {
 "propertiesForUser": {
    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser" }, 
    "accountName": "i:0#.f|membership|vardhaman@tsunami684.onmicrosoft.com",
    "propertyNames": ["PreferredName", "Department"]
     }
};

var requestHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
};


var oldurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/siteusers";   

jQuery.ajax({
    url : oldurl,
    type : "GET",
    data: JSON.stringify(theData),
    headers: requestHeaders,
    success:function(data){
        var f = JSON.stringify(data);
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error:function(jqxr,errorCode,errorThrown){
        alert(jqxr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Rereading your question and comments below, I realized I had misunderstood the question.  You have a user profile property, Job Title, and want to filter for users where Job Title == "Title".  Unfortunately, after going through the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn790354.aspx), I don't see a way to filter user profiles based on a user profile property.  You may have to get all users, and filter through returned data after.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a filter

```
 url : _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
 "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('"+ groupName +"')/Users?$filter=Id eq
 " + _spPageContextInfo.userId
```

Note: For the group you are testing make sure to change the group settings to – "Who can view the membership of the group?" = Everyone

Greetings :)

Comment: Why does this need groups, can we simply not just target everyone?

Comment: Sure you can, but your title says "get users by role", if you dont want to filter by an specific group, just remove the getByName method.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but I assumed that by role, the OP was talking about role assignments.  For example, all users with contribute.

Comment: Actually in my case role would be job title.

Comment: And how can I check for multiple job titles, like if its A or B or C, and also if there is a space in the value, like 'this job' how can I put it in the url? How do I encode the spaces basically?

Comment: @omega javascript has `encodeURIComponent()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).  Though, I've done requests without encoding the spaces, and it still works.

Comment: but what about the Or operator, how is that done?

Comment: @omega `?$filter=Title eq 'John' OR Title eq 'Bob'`.  I believe OR must be in caps.  Strings must be in single quotes.

Comment: How can I get the list of possible field values, because when I try `JobTitle`, it says `{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Field or property \"JobTitle\" does not exist."}}}`